# How can I setup this Android xml layout in good format?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created this following xml layout but it is not displaying EditText Name & Email in good format. How can I solve this problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Here I have used the weight sum 3 and layout weight 1

Answer (score 0):

At First Share Your **XML**

> LinearLayout that use the layout_weight parameter can be especially
>   expensive as each child needs to be measured twice.

**android:weightSum**

> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by
>   adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for
>   instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by
>   giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.

You can check **[Android LinearLayout example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-linearlayout-example/)**

> In the android linear layout, wight pram place some main role for the
>   different supporting resolutions. I mean by using wightsum in the
>   linear layout in android it will scale it out the total screen.

Quote from **[Weight/Weight sum in android](http://www.7solutions.in/2013/10/weightweight-sum-in-android.html)**

Example

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/edittext"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/enter_text" android:inputType="text" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro... :)

Comment: @PankajLagad Move ahead .